# Neo4j embedded only stores inside one runtime

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm experimenting with Neo4J via Embedded Java API.
My Build path seems ok (no Exceptions during runtime).
When I create some nodes and relations, I can query it directly after it with success.
But after shutting down and re-run my programm, i'm only getting the data I created in the new runtime and none of them before.
But if I look at my directory, I see, that the size has grown with each runtime, I perform a creating of data.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GraphDatabaseService gdb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( "/mytestdb/" );

    create( gdb );
    query( gdb );

    gdb.shutdown();
}

private static void query( GraphDatabaseService gdb )
{
    StringLogger sl = StringLogger.wrap( new Writer()
    {

        @Override
        public void write( char[] arg0, int arg1, int arg2 ) throws IOException
        {
            for( int i=arg1; i<=arg2; i++ ) System.out.print( arg0[i] );

        }

        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException
        {}

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException
        {}
    } );
    ExecutionEngine ee = new ExecutionEngine( gdb, sl );
    ExecutionResult result = ee.execute( "MATCH (p:Privilleg) RETURN p" );
    System.out.println( result.dumpToString() );
}

private static void create( GraphDatabaseService gdb )
{
    Transaction tx = gdb.beginTx(); 
    Node project = gdb.createNode( MyLabels.Project );
    Node user = gdb.createNode( MyLabels.User );
    Node priv1 = gdb.createNode( MyLabels.Privilleg );
    Node priv2 = gdb.createNode( MyLabels.Privilleg );

    user.setProperty( "name", "Heinz" );
    user.setProperty( "email", "heinz@gmx.net" );
    priv1.setProperty( "name", "Allowed to read all" );
    priv1.setProperty( "targets", Short.MAX_VALUE );
    priv1.setProperty( "read", true );
    priv1.setProperty( "write", false );
    priv2.setProperty( "name", "Allowed to write all" );
    priv2.setProperty( "targets", Short.MAX_VALUE );
    priv2.setProperty( "read", false );
    priv2.setProperty( "write", true );
    project.setProperty( "name", "My first project" );
    project.setProperty( "sname", "STARTUP" );
    user.createRelationshipTo( priv1, MyRelationships.UserPrivilleg );
    user.createRelationshipTo( priv2, MyRelationships.UserPrivilleg );
    priv1.createRelationshipTo( project, MyRelationships.ProjectPrivilleg );
    priv2.createRelationshipTo( project, MyRelationships.ProjectPrivilleg );
    tx.success();
}
```

Comment: Read tag descriptions before adding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't close the transaction. Typically you use a try-with-resources block:

```
try (Transaction tx=gdb.beginTx()) {
    // do stuff in the graph
    tx.success();
}
```

Since `Transaction` is `AutoClosable` its `close()` method will be called implicitly upon leaving the code block. If (for whatever) reason you decide not to use try-with-resources, be sure to explicitly call `close()`.

On a different notice: your code uses `ExecutionEngine`. Since Neo4j 2.2 you directly call `gdb.execute(myCypherString)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! This works.
Also, before I closed the transaction, it takes about 20 seconds to shuting down the db. This also is now less than a second.

Comment: yep Neo4j waits up to 20 seconds for open transactions to finish